# deploying basic angularjs app

Tags: angularjs, deployment

What do you need to deploy a simple AngularJS app on a server? I have never done any kind of deployment before.

The app is really basic and contains a few html files and one js file which contains the module, config, controller and a few variables. I run the app locally using brackets

What do I need to deploy this app on a server and how do I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just upload the files to the server...

There are hundreds of articles about deploying an AngularJS application (with minifying, uglifying, etc.) but it sounds like you just want to get your application to a publicly accessible place, so you should be fine to just upload the files.